# Unable to get shopping cart data on Success.phtml

Tags: shopping-cart, order-success-page, ecommerce-tracking

On the order confirmation page, I am trying to pull all the values of the items involved in the completed purchase, so they can be injected into a tracking iFrame. I found this code [online](https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-data-shopping-cart-items-subtotal-grand-total-billing-shipping-address-magento-2.html), but it didn't work in my file for some reason:

```
    $objectManager = $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

    //get quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

    //get array of all items what can be display directly
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    //get quote items array
    $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }
    $block_methods = $item;
```

So then I tried to restart by simply assigning \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart a variable name in two different ways:

```
$cart = get_called_class("\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart");
```

and

```
$cart = get_class("\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart");
```

but those methods both caused the page to freeze. Can anybody help explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: I have not gotten a satisfactory solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in success page

```
<?php
$lid = $this->getOrderId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lid);
$items=$order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $_item):
   $_product = 
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
        echo 'ID: '.$_product->getId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$_product->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$_product->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQtyOrdered().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$_item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />"; 

endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: This caused part of my page to crash

Comment: I have updated code @Degnan

Comment: can you accept it so it could help to others too ?

Answer (score 0):

Success page Only appear when you successfully Placed an order so instead of getting data from Quote you should get data from order id because an order is already placed once you have an order id you can load it and get its data in your success.phtml file.